# Validar que no sean vacios multiples inputs

Tags: javascript, html

tengo 20 inputs en mi html y cada input tiene un id diferente, entonces antes de mandar al backend obtengo con `getElementById` el valor de cada `div` por lo que repito el `getElementById` 20 veces y verifico que sea diferente de **vacio**, como puedo obtener los valores de manera mas sencilla verificando que no sean vacios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar los atributos nativos de HTML añadiendo a cada input el atributo `required` y si estás usando ajax con jQuery puedes usar `preventDefault` para evitar que se ejecute el comportamiento normal del `submit` y tengas los beneficios del form cómo presionar `enter` para enviar el formulario y demás.

ejemplo:

```js
$("#formulario").submit(event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("formulario comprobado");

  // ejecutar ajax o cualquier cosa


})
```

```html
<form id="formulario">

  <input type="text" required><br>
  <input type="email" required><br>
  <input type="number" required><br>

  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: como obtengo los valores, tengo 3 formularios, y lo estoy usando $("#formulario1, #formulario2, #formulario3 ").submit(function(e){

Comment: Te quedó alguna duda @hubman?

Comment: ninguna gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

No es necesario que obtenga el valor de esa manera, ya que el navegador puede mostrar un mensaje de forma nativa, e incluso puede especificarle mediante una expresión regular que tipo de datos espera recibir el input:

El siguiente ejemplo lo explica mejor. Note, el atributo **required** en el **input**

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit" maxlenght="5">
</form>
```

El siguiente ejemplo hace uso del atributo **pattern**, el cual le permite especificar el formato de texto que deberá aceptar su input:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" 
pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Este ejemplo obliga al usuario a ingresar caracteres de A hasta Z, mayúsculas o minúsculas, y como máximo 3.

En cuanto al archivo PHP, en vez de obtener el valor de cada input uno a uno puede enviarlos todos, así, aunque sean 10000 inputs el código siempre será sostenible.

En este ejemplo, se envía un form con sus inputs en forma de arreglo:

```
    <form action="demoform.php" method="get">

        <input type="checkbox" name="como[]" id="como1" value="Web">
        <label for="como1">Una web</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="como[]" id="como2" value="Google">
        <label for="como2">Google</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="como[]" id="como3" value="Anuncio en prensa">
        <label for="como3">Anuncio en prensa</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="como[]" id="como4" value="Anuncio en tv">
        <label for="como4">Anuncio en tv</label>

        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

</form>
```

Note como cada input pertenece a un mismo arreglo, esto es necesario para poder recibir los valores del lado del servidor:

```
if ( !empty($_GET["como"]) && is_array($_GET["como"]) ) { 
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ( $_GET["como"] as $como ) { 
            echo "<li>";
            echo $como; 
            echo "</li>"; 
     }
     echo "</ul>";
}
```

Hacer uso de buenas prácticas como estas en sus proyectos, hará que estos sean sostenibles y escalables. Espero haberle ayudado,

Suerte!

Comment: con poner a cada input la palabra required solucionaria mi problema?

Comment: Por supuesto! Aquí puede ver como funciona. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required 
  Recuerde marcar la mejor respuesta como válida, ya que así ayudará a otras personas con el mismo problema en el futuro.Éxitos.

Comment: pero estoy usando ajax y no uso boton submit

Comment: se puede hacer aún así puedes usar un `preventDefault()` con jQuery

Comment: @EmilianoPamont pero con required? el preventDefault lo uso pero sin required asi como la respuesta de rubenHernandez

Comment: Puede hacerlo así:     `$("form").submit(function(event){
    //perform button function
    return false;
});`

Comment: O puede hacer una validación para su formulario `if($("form").valid()){ e.preventDefault(); return;` al establecer el atributo required, esto devolverá true o false

Comment: @hubman No sé si entendí bien tu comentario pero el `required` seguirá siendo valido, el unico comportamiento que no se ejecuta cómo debería es el evento `submit` lo demás continuará igual

Comment: @JoelMuñozMoran sale is not a function valid

Comment: En ese caso haga uso del plugin  https://jqueryvalidation.org/ agregue una referencia en su head así:  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js">` y aquí esta como validar su formulario de manera muy sencilla https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Answer (score 1):

Puede hacerlo con JQuery

```
$("input").each(function(){
if($(this).val()==""){
alert("vacio");
return false;
}
});
```

Con each los recorres uno a uno y vas validando u obteniendo los datos

```
var arreglo=new Array();
$("input").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()!="") arreglo.push($(this).val());
    });
```

Si deseas agregar los espacios por este metodo

```
var arreglo=new Array();
$("input").each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val())!="") arreglo.push($(this).val());
});
```

Saludos :)

Comment: Este resultado no siempre funcionará porque comprueba que el valor de los inputs no sea `==""` pero por ejemplo si el valor de un input es `==" "` no hará nada, es mejor hacerlo con utilidades nativas cómo poner *required* pues validará lo que se tenga que validar dependiendo del tipo de input

Comment: Tienes razón tendríamos que validar también el espacio o usar alguna función como $.trim() Saludos :)